What are the Episcopalian belief on saints?
I'm writing a story of sorts that has its basis in an Episcopal character who performed a great number of good and faithful deeds (caring for the sick, preaching and even claims of miracles). He was a good and faithful person.
After his tragic death, I wonder how he may be remembered or venerated? I know devotion to the saints is usually less focused on than in say, Catholicism. Would the Anglican calender, perhaps at least locally, commemorate his death? Would he get visits to his grave?

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Episcopalian churches have a degree of autonomy and what they do in the U.S. may differ from what they do in England, or in Scotland, or in Africa. Yes, they are associated with the Anglican Communion but calendars that celebrate saints may vary from one country to another.  There are about 60 Traditional Anglican Saints. It would be helpful if you could narrow the search down by settling on a particular country.

What are the Episcopalian belief on saints?
Episcopalian sainthood cases follow a somewhat different course towards being named a saint than in the Catholic Church.
Synodical assemblies have the power to declare a person a saint within the Episcopalian communities.
For example, the Church of England, the Mother Church of the Anglican Communion, canonized Charles I as a saint, in the Convocations of Canterbury and York of 1660.
** Thurgood Marshall** is now considered a candidate for sainthood in the Episcopalian Church.

When Thurgood Marshall died 13 years ago this week, he left behind a life of historic accomplishments: Intrepid warrior against Jim Crow. Architect of the landmark Brown v. Board of Education desegregation case. First black Supreme Court justice.
Now, some of Marshall's fellow Episcopalians are saying that the spiritual hallmark of his life -- his Christian commitment to racial justice -- qualifies him for special recognition. They think the Episcopal Church should name him a saint.
Delegates to the annual convention of the Episcopal Diocese of Washington will vote today on the proposal, the first step in a long process. If Marshall is added to the church's roster of saints, May 17 - the date of the 1954 Supreme Court ruling that segregated schools are unconstitutional - would be observed as Marshall Feast Day.
Church officials say they expect the 300 or so delegates to approve the resolution, which was drawn up by members of St. Augustine's Church in Southwest Washington, where Marshall worshiped.
"I haven't heard anyone say it's a bad idea," said Jim Naughton, spokesman for Bishop John Bryson Chane, who will preside at today's assembly at Washington National Cathedral.
When it comes to sainthood, Episcopalians follow a looser procedure than the Roman Catholic Church, which conducts a rigorous investigation into the life of any saint-to-be and requires proof that he or she performed at least two miracles. Candidates for Episcopal sainthood should be figures who displayed traits such as "heroic faith," "joyousness" and "service to others for Christ's sake," according to church guidelines.
Although Marshall did not speak publicly about his faith, it meant a great deal to him, said his widow, Cecilia Marshall, 78, who plans to be present when the resolution comes up for a vote.
Marshall, who died of heart failure on Jan. 24, 1993, at the age of 84, was a lifelong Episcopalian. Born in Baltimore to a Pullman car porter and a schoolteacher, he graduated from Howard University's law school in 1933.
Episcopalians Consider Sainthood for Marshall

Episcopalian Church like the Catholic Church would honour their saints with a liturgical commemoration (feast day) and would be able to venerate their saints at their grave sites
